# Open camera take photo and set it in image view in PopupWindow - android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-imageview, popupwindow

I have a PopupWindow in Android, and inside it I have a imageview. When I press the imageview I want to open the camera take a photo and when I comeback to set photo for imageview's background.

The problem is when I comeback(onActivityResult), the popupwindow is dismiss(), and the imageView background is default.

imageView@onClick:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                File photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                    Log.i(TAG, "IOException");
                }
                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
                }
            }
```

createImageFile() function

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  // prefix
            ".jpg",         // suffix
            storageDir      // directory
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();

    editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("picture_path", mCurrentPhotoPath);
    editor.commit();

    return image;
}
```

@onActivityResult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        try {

            prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            mCurrentPhotoPath = prefs.getString("picture_path", null);

            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(mCurrentPhotoPath));
            add_photo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I used Sharedpreferences to avoid null on *mCurrentPhotoPath* .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the problem is that MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap is returning null, it is because it is meant to be used to retrieve an Image from URL handled by some app in some ContentResolver, which is not the case in your implementation.

In your implementation you're storing the image on devices filesystem which you can retrieve with [BitmapFactorys](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) [decodeFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile(java.lang.String)) method that returns the bitmap.

Comment: I have to say that I've tested my code on Samsung S5 android 5.0 , and it is working. But on other devices..

Comment: You didn't really explain the problem on your question, so I was assuming the getBitmap method was returning null, was it?

Comment: no! mCurrentPhotoPath was null, but I used shared prefs to save and retirve it's value so it's ok. It doesnt  change  the picture in iMageVie, this is my problem. But on S5 I've tested and it's working... headchache....

Comment: So on some device it is not working? Because its returning null from the shared preferences? That is probably because the other device doesn't most likely have getExternalStoragePublicDirectory available, which means you need to use the internal storage directory. Have you made sure it returns a valid value in first place? Please try logging the file path you're receiving on the first place in createImageFile method

Comment: From shared preferences is always return the good path, but I dnk why it is not update my ImageView

Comment: You're absolutely positive that the bitmap returned by getBitmap call is actually a _valid_ bitmap? If you use BitmapFactory to save it on the disk, does it result in the correct picture?

Comment: I will check one more time with debugger.

Comment: 100% positive, I have the image saved on my phone , the path is correct, in one phone is working but in the others...

Comment: this is the error on logcat
`02-11 10:50:28.821 25666-25666/ro.nrsoft.misights E/ViewRootImpl: Could not lock surface
                                                                  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
                                                                      at android.view.Surface.nativeLockCanvas(Native Method)`

Comment: some updates.
I have scaled the bitmap before I set it. In some phones is working on others I got `OutOfMemoryError` or `ViewRootImpl #2 Surface is not valid`

Comment: I can't really think of a reason why nativeLockCanvas isn't succeeding, is that exception happening at the time it is trying to set the bitmap? But the reason for OutOfMemoryError is as the error name says, the device has ran out of memory, which might be because of a memory leak in your application, or otherwise allocating too big chunk of a memory, which can be overcome by loading the image in the ImageView in a smaller resolution for example.